# Wordpress directory structure

Tags: wordpress

Thanks in advance for your help.

Can you recommend a maintainable setup in Wordpress for this directory structure shown below?

Note: each conference state will have a nav linking to the child pages from directory.

```
About/
News/
Conferences/
    2018-texas
        Tickets/
        Workshops/
        Exhibitors/
        Contact/
    2018-kansascity
        Tickets/
        Workshops/
        Exhibitors/
        Contact/
    2018-sf
        Tickets/
        Workshops/
        Exhibitors/
        Contact/
    [additional states with additional pages...]
Directory/
Contact/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Create a post type named `conference`
- Create a custom taxonomy named `city` or `state`
- Create a custom taxonomy named `year`
- Use ACF to create fields to add `Tickets, Workshops, etc`

When adding a new post, you would select a title for the conference, then a year and a state. This way you can easily add years and more states in future.

You can create a page called `conferences` and loop through all posts published in `conference` post type and display related fields.